# TeamCity executing custom build manually

Tags: teamcity

We have the following chained build configurations in a TeamCity project:

1. Build (automatic, triggered by check-ins)
2. Run tests (automatic, triggered by step 1)
3. Deploy to Acceptance (automatic, triggered by step 1)
4. Deploy to Staging (manual)”)

With this configuration, how can we automate the following task: “Choose ‘changeset xxx’ from the changeset history and use it in the following steps: 1. Build > 2. Run tests > 4. Deploy to Staging”, so it's ideally a one-click process?

Comment: I tried all I could, but I am failing to understand HOW to achieve this task in TeamCity.

Answer (score 0):

The feature I was looking for in TeamCity is called "Promote Build".

I managed to solve this by adding "1. Build" and "2. Run tests" in the Build Configuration Settings > Dependencies of "4. Deploy to staging".
Now, let's say that the latest version of my app is v0.0.002, but I want to deploy a previously build version v0.0.001 to Staging. To do that, I'll go to "1. Build" > Build History > v.0.0.001 > Actions > Promote and choose to promote it to "4. Staging"